# What's difference values(1 2 3) of google_conversion_format?

Tags: adsense

What's difference values(1,2,3) of google_conversion_format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

google_conversion_format: tells Google whether you want to display their little bug on your thank you page and how it will appear.

Comment: Thanks, do you know what each values means?

Comment: I don't know exactly.  I know they're generated based on the choices you select as you follow the ad words wizard.  Sorry mate.

Comment: @UncleIroh is right. See proof here: http://www.bytefive.com/pay-per-click/track-conversions-google-adwords/

Answer (score 17):

1: shows a 1-line notification to visitors

2: shows a 2-line notification to visitors

3: no notification to visitors

The notification is

```
Google Site Stats
_learn more_
```

There are also parameters for color and language.

Google recommends 1 or 2 for this reason:

> Add Google Site Stats to earn your customers' trust and help them to
>   make informed decisions.
>
> What it means: A small message will appear on your site telling
>   customers that their visits on your site are being tracked. We
>   recommend you use it.
>
> Why it matters: Honesty lets customers make informed decisions about
>   their visits, and it reflects positively on your business.
>
> What to do: Add your own message or privacy policy to your website or
>   select the "Google Site Stats" option to have a message added
>   automatically.