# Google Adwords Conversion Tags

Tags: tags, e-commerce, google-ads-api

What is the real purpose of these variables?

google_conversion_format and google_conversion_color

In what cases, i'll see the application of these tags?

Answer (score 0):

google_conversion_format (to show notifications to the user):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/16108587/1763732

google_conversion_color (to choose the color of the notification):

http://www.wordstream.com/blog/ws/2013/08/13/adwords-conversion-tracking-guide